# Why does the homology of noncompact manifolds often vanish below the dimension?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

So I was watching [this talk by Peter Scholze](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtOWsaEGKcA&t=170s), where at around 9:50 he says that the homology of the quotient $X := H^3/SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[i])$ only has homology in degrees 0, 1, and 2, because it's noncompact. Here $H^3$ is hyperbolic upper 3-space. (I understand that homology must vanish beyond degree 3, so the question is why the top dimensional homology vanishes)

I'm trying to understand why the noncompactness makes the 3-dimensional homology vanish. In particular I'd be interested in the relevant facts/theorems, and if possible, references would be awesome.

Other simpler but enlightening examples would be appreciated as well.

As a side question - this space $X$ is triangularizable right?

Comment: Since $X$ is three dimensional, it only has possibly nonvanishing cohomology in degress $0,1,2$ and $3$, and has vanishing top cohomology by virtue of it being non-compact.

Comment: In the orientable case, use Poincaré duality for de Rham cohomology to relate the top cohomology group with the zeroth compactly supported cohomology group, and compute the latter.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Right, so the question is why non-compactness forces the top dimensional homology to vanish. Separately, is it always true that a non-compact manifold has vanishing top dimensional homology?

Comment: On your side question, any smooth manifold is triangulable.

Comment: For complex algebraic variety there is a stronger statement : for any analytic variety $X \subset \mathbb C^n$, the homology $H_i(X) = 0$ for $i > n$ where $n = \dim X$ is the _complex_ dimension (so it has real dimension $2n$ : half of its homology vanishes !).

Comment: For a hand-wavey intuition-type answer, if a manifold is not-compact, then you think of it as having holes/punctures (possibly 'at infinity') and we can deformation retract the manifold away from those holes onto some compact subcomplex (think for instance of the $(n+1)$-punctured sphere deformation retracting onto a wedge of $n$ circles). I'm not sure if this can be made rigorous, but hopefully it at least helps with intuition.

Comment: Spivak (vol 1, 3ed) has this as Theorem 10, page 272, independent of Poincaré duality. But I do not think the cover he uses in the proof actually exists unless the manifold has a finite number of ends.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a consequence of Poincare duality.  Let $X$ be a connected $n$-manifold (without boundary).  Then by Poincare duality, there is an isomorphism $H_n(X;\mathbb{Z})\cong H^0_c(X;\omega)$ where $\omega$ is the orientation local system of $X$.  Now if $X$ is not compact, $H^0_c(X;A)=0$ for any local system $A$.  Indeed, if $\alpha$ is any nonzero compactly supported $0$-cochain on $X$, let $\gamma$ be a singular $1$-simplex (i.e., a path) in $X$ which starts at a point in the support of $\alpha$ and ends at a point not in the support of $\alpha$.  Then $\alpha(\partial\gamma)$ is nonzero.  Thus $\alpha$ is not a cocycle.  So there are no nonzero compactly supported $0$-cocycles, and so $H^0_c(X;A)=0$ trivially.

Thus if $X$ is a connected non-compact $n$-manifold, $H_n(X;\mathbb{Z})=0$.

Comment: In the OP's example the quotient space is indeed a manifold even though the arithmetic group $SL(2, Z[i])$ is not torsion-free.

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!